# If search contains "pc" search another site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to check if the search contains a string "pc".  If the search contains pc i want to redirect to another URL removing the term "pc" from the query and leaving the rest.

This should look like this:

[www.somesite.com/?s=pc12121212](http://www.somesite.com/?s=pc12121212)   ----> sub.somesite.com/index.php?p=12121212

Comment: OK. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code.  Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

```
function CheckAndMove(url){
    const queries = url.split('?')[1]
    if(!queries) return; // leave if you have no queries at all

    const search = (new URLSearchParams(queries)).get('s') // extract the search query
    if(!search || !search.indexOf('pc')==-1) return // leave if you have no search query or it doesn't contain pc

    const id = search.replace('pc','') // remove the 'pc' part
    window.location = 'https://www.sub.somesite.com/index.php?p='+id;
}
```